# Fluids pressure and Perturbation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics

Suppose the fluid pressure is given by $p = p_0 +c^2(ρ−ρ_0)$, where $p_0, ρ_0, $and  c are positive constants. Consider small perturbations to a uniform rest state with density $ρ_0$, so that ρ = $ρ_0 + ρ'$. Show that ρ' and the velocity potential φ satisfy the wave equations
$$ \frac{∂^2φ}{∂_t^2}−c^2∇^2φ=0$$
$$\frac{∂^2\rho'}{∂t^2}−c^2∇^2ρ'=0,$$ and find a relation between φ and ρ′.

My idea is to use the Euler equation $\frac{∂\rho}{∂t}$+$\nabla \cdot (\rho \mathbf u)=0$ and $\rho\frac {D\mathbf u}{Dt}=-\nabla p$ But how to use the relationship between p and $\rho$

Plug in to the equation I have:

first equation$$\frac{∂\rho'}{∂t}+\nabla \bullet (\rho'\mathbf u)=0$$

second equation$$(\rho_0+\rho')(\frac{∂\mathbf u}{∂t}+(\mathbf u\bullet\nabla)\mathbf u)=-\nabla c^2\rho'$$ Then how should I continue?

Comment: How is $\phi$ defined? But if they say $p_0$, $\rho_0$ and c are positive constants, then they will not really contribute to the wave equation since it is only a translation of the solution. I don't really understand why you are looking for $p$. You can just insert $p$ as they are given to you.

Comment: It is the velocity potential. Yes, I tried to insert but don't know what convert to the second derivative.

Comment: Ah now I understand. You are trying to find second time derivative. Take the time derivative of your second equation. As far as I can remember the velocity field is just the gradient of the velocity potential. The right hand side can then be solved by using the compressibility in term of the density to establish a relation to the pressure.

Comment: you should really better post such questions on physic SE. There are a lot of assumption that one need to made which is not mathematical at all.

Comment: @quallenjäger I edited my post can you please help me to look at it? Thank you so much!

Comment: I am giving another try..

Comment: You should mainly work with the second equation. First assume you can write $Du/Dt$ in $\partial u/\partial t$, then take time derivative on both side. Furthermore you need assume that you can exchange time derivative and gradient to write $\nabla \partial / \partial t$ then you will see a better shape by cancelling $\nabla$ on both side. On the right hand side you are left with a time Derivate of $p$.

Comment: @quallenjäger I plug in the equation but I am confused about the second time derivative of the right-hand side and how to take the gradient of both sides that leads to the cancelling. Can you give my more hint?

Comment: https://www.phy.ornl.gov/csep/sw/node4.html

Comment: I do not quite understand can you give me more hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple application of perturbation theory to the Euler equations. So, you will have
$$
\rho=\rho_0+\epsilon\rho'
$$
and
$$
{\bf u}={\bf u}_0-\epsilon\nabla\phi.
$$
I have introduced $\epsilon$ as a bookeeping and I will set it to 1 to the end of the computation. Now, from the continuity equation
$$
  \epsilon\frac{\partial\rho'}{\partial t}+\nabla[(\rho_0+\epsilon\rho')({\bf u}_0-\epsilon\nabla\phi)]=0
$$
Then, expand and take all the derivative of $\rho_0$ and ${\bf u}_0$ to 0. You will get
$$
   \epsilon\frac{\partial\rho'}{\partial t}+
   \nabla\cdot(\rho_0{\bf u}_0)+
   {\epsilon}{\bf u}_0\cdot\nabla\rho'-\epsilon\rho_0\Delta_2\phi+O(\epsilon^2)=0.
$$
From the other equation you will get
$$
   -\epsilon\nabla\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}
-\epsilon{\bf u}_o\cdot\nabla(\nabla\phi)=-c^2\frac{\nabla\rho'}{\rho_0}+O(\epsilon^2).
$$
where I used the equation $p=p_0+c^2(\rho-\rho_0)$ on the right hand side. Now, ${\bf u}_0$ is a constant vector and we can take it to be 0 without loss of generality (we are studying sound waves in an otherwise static fluid) and so, we have the first order approximation
$$
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}=c^2\frac{\rho'}{\rho_0}
$$
where I have chosen an integration contribution being 0. If you put this in the continuity equation at the same order you will get
$$
  \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}-\Delta_2\phi=0
$$
as required. You see that several approximations have been done in different stages of this derivation. To get the equation for the density, just derive the continuity equation with respect to time and use the equation between $\rho'$ and $\phi$ and you are done.

ADDED ON OP'S REQUEST: To derive the second equation I have to consider
$$
   \epsilon\frac{\partial\rho'}{\partial t}+
   \nabla\cdot(\rho_0{\bf u}_0)+
   {\epsilon}{\bf u}_0\cdot\nabla\rho'-\epsilon\rho_0\Delta_2\phi+O(\epsilon^2)=0.
$$
that becomes
$$
   \epsilon\frac{\partial\rho'}{\partial t}+\epsilon\rho_0\Delta_2\phi+O(\epsilon^2)=0.
$$
Now, from the other Euler equation is
$$
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}=c^2\frac{\rho'}{\rho_0}. \qquad   {\bf (1)}
$$
Then, I take the derivative of the first yielding at order $\epsilon$
$$
   \frac{\partial^2\rho'}{\partial t^2}+\rho_0\Delta_2\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}=0.
$$
and using eq.(1) one has
$$
  \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\rho'}{\partial t^2}-\Delta_2\rho'=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to understand step by step.

Comment: Can you explain more about how you get  from the second equation?

Comment: You multiply the two factors inside the nabla do you have $\nabla(\rho_0{\bf u}_0+\epsilon\rho'{\bf u}_0+\epsilon\rho_0\nabla\phi)+O(\epsilon^2)$. Then, ${\bf u_0}=0$ and you have done. I have to fix a term $\nabla\cdot(\rho_0{\bf u}_0)$ in that formula anyhow.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand

Comment: Please, let me know better what is your concern and I will expand my answer.

Comment: Can you explain it just based on the multi-calculus knowledge if it is convenient?

Comment: This is standard perturbation theory as usually applied to the case of sound waves. What do you mean by multi-calculus knowledge?

Comment: I had only learned it from a math perspective so I don't know the perturb theory. It maybe a little hard for my to understand.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I have another question: So after approximation, what do you mean to put this in the continuity equation in the same order?

Comment: The bookkeeping for the order is given by $\epsilon$. So, I mean to collect all the terms containing $\epsilon$ because we stop at this order and neglect higher powers of $\epsilon$. At the end of computation you can forget about it fixing its value to 1.

Comment: Can you add the equation explicitly in the post? I am still quite confused.

Comment: I have expanded the answer.

Comment: Yes. I finally get it. It really makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Another question: if we know this, can we figure out the relation between  $ϕ $ and $ \rho'$

Comment: Yes, of course.  It is eq.(1) in the addendum.

Comment: Thank you! If you have time can you help me look at another fluids and wave problem? Thank you! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283188/fluids-eulers-equation